# Qt Creator "Cannot create file (...) qtcreator.xml" (Mac)

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Qt Creator starts up with several error messages saying that:
"Cannot create file /Users/[username]/.config/Nokia/qtcreator.xml: Permission denied"

And when I exit:
"Cannot create file /Users/[username]/.config/Nokia/toolChains.xml: Permission denied"

The program runs fine, but I guess it won't be able to store any config. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Found solution by examining folder ownership. Turns out Qt installer created the "user/.config" directory as root. 

Changed user with [chown][1] command to my user, and made sure I had "rwx" permissions and now it works fine.


[1]: http://ss64.com/osx/chown.html

Comment: Can you check if ".config" folder already exists in your home folder? What happens if you create ".config" folder manually and try starting Qt Creator again? My guess would be that you probably have a file with the same name (".config") in your home folder. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Wow, not professional at all! But then I installed using `brew`

Comment: Lol, in my case it collided with .config file from crosstools-ng

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, it looks like the Qt installer adds the configuration directories with root as the owner. To fix this, run:

```
sudo chown -R `id -un`:staff ~/.config/Nokia/
```

Answer (score -1):

this command works great for me. found it in [qtcenter forum](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/45538-S-Privileges-Permissions-problems-after-running-Qt-Creator-with-priviliges-on-Linux)

```
find ~/.config/Nokia -print0 | sudo xargs -0 chown $USER
```

i use this instead for version 2.6.1 Qt 5

```
find ~/.config/QtProject -print0 | sudo xargs -0 chown $USER
```