# Qt Creator Error Messages Mac OS 10.9

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator

"Cannot create file /Users/[username]/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/qtversion.xml: No such file or directory"

I get this message 4 or 5 times upon startup. I did a clean install today. This is different than the permission problem error I found earlier on here. The installer did not create a .config file or I cannot see it or access it. How do I fix this error?

Comment: A maybe-hotfix: mkdir /Users/[username]/.config/QtProject/qtcreator . Does it work?

Comment: Or, rather, `mkdir -p $HOME/.config/QtProject/qtcreator`

Comment: Thanks guys! Specifically @KubaOber exact code worked. I don't know why I didn't think to create the directory myself. I was concerned that I needed to build the library based on some of the instructions on the Qt website.

Once the file is created the permissions need to be changed. I used this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530111/qt-creator-cannot-create-file-qtcreator-xml-mac